# How to prevent others to access codebehinde in the panel instead compile way?

Tags: asp.net, iis, host

I want to deny other people to read my C# code in the host panel (Websitepanel), but don't want to prevent showing website.

Can I set password for directories?

How can I do this without compile way ?

Best regards.

Comment: What other people are you talking about?

Comment: @CodeCaster People that have host panel password and can access code files in host.

Comment: Well then no. If you upload plain text code files to a web host, anyone who can access that site's "host panel" can access those files.